# Gunicorn configuration - I think I might have done it wrong?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

This is my first time configuring gunicorn. I've used a tutorial from DigitalOcean but I can't make it work.

My files are like this: `home/octavian56/robotics.carabella.ro/venv` (here is the venv with bin and stuff)/robotics (with `manage.py` and stuff)

Here is the `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=octavian56
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/octavian56/robotics.carabella.ro
ExecStart=/home/octavian56/robotics.carabella.ro/venv/robotics/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/octavian56/robotics.carabella.ro/venv/robotics/bin/robotics.sock robotics.wsgi:application
```

`Error`:

> Apr 16 12:03:51 robotics.carabella.ro gunicorn[26284]:     return
>   util.import_app(self.app_uri) Apr 16 12:03:51 robotics.carabella.ro
>   gunicorn[26284]:   File
>   "/home/octavian56/robotics.carabella.ro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
>   line 350 Apr 16 12:03:51 robotics.carabella.ro gunicorn[26284]:
>   **import**(module) Apr 16 12:03:51 robotics.carabella.ro gunicorn[26284]: ImportError: No module named robotics.wsgi Apr 16
>   12:03:51 robotics.carabella.ro gunicorn[26284]: [2019-04-16 12:03:51
>   +0000] [26289] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 26289) Apr 16 12:03:51 robotics.carabella.ro gunicorn[26284]: [2019-04-16 12:03:51 +0000]
>   [26284] [INFO] Shutting down: Master Apr 16 12:03:51
>   robotics.carabella.ro gunicorn[26284]: [2019-04-16 12:03:51 +0000]
>   [26284] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot. Apr 16 12:03:51
>   robotics.carabella.ro systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process
>   exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED Apr 16 12:03:51
>   robotics.carabella.ro systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered
>   failed state. Apr 16 12:03:51 robotics.carabella.ro systemd[1]:
>   gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. lines 1-16/16 (END)

Please, help me explain how should I properly configure this.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: you should address where `wsgi.py` file exists , error simply says can't find `wsgi.py` file

Comment: Please show your project structure. Where is the wsgi file?

Comment: I can't even copy it because there are too many folders. I tried to show it in the post.

Comment: wsgi.py is located in /home/octavian56/robotics.carabella.ro/venv/robotics/robotics, along settings.py and the others.

Answer (score 1):

Add at the end

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Or probably you have something wrong with path in **--bind**. I think it should be like this:

```
-bind unix:/home/octavian56/robotics.carabella.ro/robotics.sock robotics.wsgi:application
```

Comment: I've changed it like you said, and here's the error:

Comment: Try to set `-bind unix:/home/octavian56/robotics.carabella.ro/venv/robotics/robotics.sock robotics.wsgi:application`. Main problem is with acces to your wsgi file.

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know what happened, it work for a second until I restarted it. Here's the error: